# Way to check overlaps of a collider2d that's not set to "is trigger" in Unity

Tags: unity, box2d

I have a system where physics2d objects are spawned and I need to know when they spawn outside of a region defined by a box collider set to "is Trigger".

Using onTriggerEnter and onTriggerExit to know if an object exits / re-enters the bounds (with some other conditions determining whether to kill the object when it exits the bounds). That stuff works fine.

However I can't detect when an object spawns outside of the collider (which I want to allow, but just know when it happens).

I tried the following in the Start method of the spawned object:

```
List<Collider2D> results = new List<Collider2D>();
_boundsCollider.OverlapCollider(new ContactFilter2D(), results);
bool spawned_outside = !results.Contains(_thisCollider);
```

However at the time that method runs, the booundsCollider doesn't register it. Subsequent frames it will, but that's too late.

OverlapCollder can't be run on the collider for the spawned object since it isn't set as a trigger.

Is there any way I can query the spawned object's own collider to determine if it is in contact with the bounds collider?

Thanks!

PS I can't trivially just reference the coords of the object and check if they're out of bounds because the bounds collider will move, and I want to know with precision wether just a corner is overlapping or whatever so I'd need something that amounts to my own simple collision system

Comment: Can you tell us anything about the shapes of these colliders? If you're using simple primitives like boxes/circles/capsules, we might be able to check this with pure math, without waiting for a physics tick to detect collider interactions.

Comment: Right now, just boxes. I'd certainly like to know that math! but I also want to allow for more complex colliders in the future

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ["Awake()"](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Awake.html) behavior on the objects you want to detect spawning, and just implement the code you mentioned above:

```
List<Collider2D> results = new List<Collider2D>();
_boundsCollider.OverlapCollider(new ContactFilter2D(), results);
bool spawned_outside = !results.Contains(_thisCollider);
```

As you can see [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html) that's called at the stage where the objects are actually initialized.

What behavior are you experiencing with calling it at "Start()" that's making it too late?

Comment: Alas the problem is the other way around. It isn't that the code I posted is running too late - it's that at the time it runs in either Awake or Start, the other collider (boundsCollider) hasn't yet detected the overlap. So "results.Contains(_thisCollider)" will return false, even though it's true, until a physics update has happened, which is what I meant by 'too late'.

Comment: Did you try [Physics2D.SyncTransforms](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.SyncTransforms.html) to inform the physics engine of the position of the newly-spawned collider?

Comment: @DMGregory no dice :(

Comment: @arcadeperfect Are you able to check the distance between the object that you're spawning, and the collider? Something like: if(Vector3.Distance(Collider.transform.position, gameObject.transform.position) > [colliders radius]) { // do things if the distance to collider at spawn is less then the colliders radius }

Answer (score 0):

You could just get the bounds of the collider and check whether the objects are within the bounds, then you wouldn't have to check overlap at all.

Heres an example

```
public BoxCollider2D box;

void Start() {
    Bounds bounds = box.bounds
    if (transform.position.x < bounds.min.x)
```

Obviously you wouldn't just check whether its outside of the left bounds you would want other checks too however it may work for you.

Alternatively there is a Bounds.Contains() function but I'm not sure the implications of that.

Comment: This code only tests if a single point is to the left of the leftmost edge of a box collider. There could still be an overlap in this case, if the shape extends rightward from its pivot point.

Comment: thats why I said _"Obviously you wouldn't just check whether its outside of the left bounds you would want other checks too however it may work for you."_ assuming thats what you're talking about. If thats too vague I mean you would also have something like `if (transform.position.x < bounds.min.x && transform.position.x > bounds.max.x && ...)`

Comment: This still does not take into account the shape and size of "this" object, only the shape and size of the container.